# Google Calendar API - Group Attendee Emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-calendar-api

For Google Calendar API v3, is there a way to expand an [Attendee Group](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/172013?hl=en) so that when the API returns a [Calendar Event](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events) object, it returns all the Attendees in that group instead of simply returning the "group" as an Attendee.

Currently, if I invite a Group (i.e.: All Staff), the API returns the attendee group as if it was a single attendee.

```
<Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventAttendee:0x000000000292b3f8 @email="attendee1@gmail.com", @response_status="declined", @display_name="Attendee One">, 
<Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventAttendee:0x00000000028d0b88 @email="all_staff@gmail.com", @response_status="needsAction", @display_name="All Staff">]
```

Instead, it would be more useful to expand the group and output all the attendees and their respective responses.

```
<Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventAttendee:0x000000000292b3f8 @email="attendee1@gmail.com", @response_status="declined", @display_name="Attendee One">, 
<Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventAttendee:0x000000000292b3f8 @email="attendee2@gmail.com", @response_status="declined", @display_name="Attendee 2">
<Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventAttendee:0x000000000292b3f8 @email="attendee3@gmail.com", @response_status="needsAction", @display_name="Attendee 3">
<Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventAttendee:0x000000000292b3f8 @email="attendee4@gmail.com", @response_status="attending", @display_name="Attendee 4">
```

Comment: your question is unclear please edit it and add enough information so that we can understand what you are referring to.  Add your code and the output and describe the issue you are having with the output in detail

Comment: To help you start with, you can refer to the [documentation of Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/ruby). Also, to learn more about attendees, you can refer [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/sharing).

Answer (score 2):

Update: Google Calendar API does not currently support the functionality to expand Attendee Groups to add individual attendees within the group as Event Attendees.

Comment: Is there any solution available now ?

Answer (score 0):

afak there is no way to distinct a normal email from a group email. But, when you get the event attendees, you can regex on it based on your group email name. Then using [Google Directory Api](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory) you can expand the list of the group email members using [manage-group-members](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-group-members):

```
# If you try to get the members list of a user email you'll get 'returned "Resource Not Found: groupKey"
    page_token = None
    result = []
    try:
        while True:
            members = directory_service.members().list(groupKey=email, includeDerivedMembership=True).execute()
            result = [member for member in members.get('members') if member['type'] == 'USER'
                      and member['status'] == 'ACTIVE']
            page_token = members.get('nextPageToken')
            if not page_token:
                break
        return result
    except:
        logger.exception('get_group_members: ')
```

But, you don't know what is their responseStatus for that event, unless you check each own personal calendar. If anyone know how to check the responseStatus from each group email member to an event invitation, it would be great to know.